# Do colimits preserve free group actions?

Tags: category-theory, equivariant-maps

Suppose $C$ is a small category, $M$ is a category and $G$ is a discrete group. Let $X$ be a $G$-object in $M^C$ and suppose that the action of $G$ on $X$ is object-wise free. Under what conditions is the action of $G$ on $colim_C X$ again free?

Comment: Under a $G$-object $X$ I'd understand a functor $A\colon G\to M^C$, mapping the single object $*$ in $G$ to a functor $X\colon C\to M$, and group objects $g$ to natural isomorphisms $\gamma^g\colon X\to X$, or more specific, to a family of isomorphisms $(\gamma_x^g\colon X(x)\to X(x))_{x\in\operatorname{Ob}(C)}$ satisfying $X(f)\circ \gamma_x^g = \gamma_x^g \circ X(f)$ for all $f$ in $C(x,x)$. So by "$G$ acts object-wise free" you mean that $\gamma_x^g$ acts freely on $x$ for all $x$ in $\operatorname{Ob}(C)$? (Which would require $M$ to be concrete, otherwise I don't know how to define free)

Comment: Uhm, I meant $\gamma^g_x$ acts freely on $X(x)$ for all $x\in\operatorname{Ob}(C)$ in my last sentence...

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean by ``object-wise free action''. I am actually interested in the case where $M$ is the category of simplicial sets.